# Customer Login and Other Top Menu Links Not clickable (Magento)

Tags: magento, menu

Please help me with this.

I just noticed that top menu links of my website are not clickable. I didn't update or change any file before I noticed this bug.

Is anyone have experienced problem like this before?

Comment: Hi Friend,Can you please send your site link so that I can check if there is something fishy ?

Comment: Sounds like you have an element over the top of them with a visible/opacity rule making it seem like it isn't there. If you have something that is fixed over that position in the DOM, use display:none to hide it and prevent it from stealing mouse focus.